# Can't install Certbot for Apache on CentOS Stream 9 (python3-certbot)

Tags: centos, yum, dnf, certbot

On Centos Stream 9, when I try to install certbot (`sudo yum install certbot`) into the server it returns:

```
Error: 
 Problem: package certbot-1.22.0-1.el8.noarch requires python3-certbot = 1.22.0-1.el8, but none of the providers can be installed
  - conflicting requests
  - nothing provides python3.6dist(setuptools) >= 39.0.1 needed by python3-certbot-1.22.0-1.el8.noarch
  - nothing provides python3.6dist(cryptography) >= 2.5.0 needed by python3-certbot-1.22.0-1.el8.noarch
  - nothing provides python3.6dist(configobj) >= 5.0.6 needed by python3-certbot-1.22.0-1.el8.noarch
  - nothing provides python3.6dist(distro) >= 1.0.1 needed by python3-certbot-1.22.0-1.el8.noarch
  - nothing provides /usr/bin/python3.6 needed by python3-certbot-1.22.0-1.el8.noarch
  - nothing provides python3.6dist(pytz) needed by python3-certbot-1.22.0-1.el8.noarch
  - nothing provides python(abi) = 3.6 needed by python3-certbot-1.22.0-1.el8.noarch
(try to add '--skip-broken' to skip uninstallable packages or '--nobest' to use not only best candidate packages)
```

I've tried to install python3-certbot from the official site but also returned this error.
Also, I tried to set PowerTools on but seems like the repo didn't exist so I couldn't.
Is there a way that I can install certbot?

Comment: `certbot-1.22.0-1.el8.noarch` this a CentOS 8 package, which repository are you trying to install certbot from?

Comment: I don't know where are those repositories from, but I think it comes from the default server since I didn't change anything about the source server.

Comment: I believe this is now available.  `yum install -y certbot` or `dnf install -y certbot`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no **certbot** for Centos Stream 9. It's not present in the epel, nor epel-next repo, nor is snapd. So you will have to wait, until it is released for Centos 9. The packages you have in your repositories, are for Centos 8. They will never work.

Answer (score 3):

There's no a dnf package now, but a snap one. Refer to:

https://certbot.eff.org/instructions?ws=apache&os=centosrhel8

All command lines are:

---

```
dnf config-manager --set-enabled crb
dnf install https://dl.fedoraproject.org/pub/epel/epel-release-latest-9.noarch.rpm
dnf install https://dl.fedoraproject.org/pub/epel/epel-next-release-latest-9.noarch.rpm

dnf list|grep snapd
dnf install snapd

systemctl enable snapd
systemctl start snapd
systemctl status snapd

snap install core
ln -s /var/lib/snapd/snap /snap
snap install --classic certbot
ln -s /snap/bin/certbot /usr/bin/certbot

systemctl list-timers
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe this is now available.

`yum install -y certbot`

or

`dnf install -y certbot`